# How to add pandas time stamp to a dataframe post read_cvs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

How can I attribute a timestamp in my data frame after reading the cvs file? I have a data set with measurements, but no time stamp. I know the frequency of the sensor data (200 Hz) and the start date/time.

I have tried to count the number of lines in my file and creating a time column. Using pd.insert I've inserted this time stamp. My problem is that when plotting these data, my x-axis does not show the attributed timestamps but rather the number of measurement. My code:

```py
    #Importing signals 
    data = pd.read_csv('.../monday.txt')
    data.columns = ['l1','l2','l3','l4','l5','l6']

    print("Sensor data: ")
    print(data.head())
    print(data.dtypes)

    nbrMeasurments = sum(1 for line in open('.../monday.txt'))
    data.insert(0, "Time", pd.timedelta_range('11:24:26', 
    periods=nbrMeasurments-1, freq="5L"))

    print("Revised sensor data: ")
    print(data.head())
    print(data.dtypes)
```

In another file where there is a time stamps, it looks like the "index_col='Date'" in `pd.read_csv('.../mondayV1.csv',index_col='Date',  usecols= [0,1,2], parse_dates=True)` is the command that ensures that the x-axis is referenced by date and not measurment number "x":

```py
                         SYS (mmHg)  DIA (mmHg)
    Date                                       
    2019-08-07 13:06:30         111          61
    2019-08-07 13:07:08         114          64
    2019-08-07 13:07:56         112          63
    2019-08-07 13:08:42         127          81
    2019-08-07 13:09:19         129          83
    Omron data types: 
    SYS (mmHg)    int64
    DIA (mmHg)    int64
```

With my insert attempt with the file without timestamp, "Time" is listed as a vaiable:

```
                 Time        l1        l2        l3        l4       l5       
    l6
    0        11:24:26  0.787261  0.943828  1.100903  0.835889  2.524946  
    2.252113
    1 11:24:26.005000  0.787068  0.943638  1.100871  0.835882  2.531180  
    2.253063
    2 11:24:26.010000  0.786951  0.943496  1.100779  0.835909  2.531573  
    2.253395
    3 11:24:26.015000  0.786879  0.943553  1.100877  0.835877  2.533841  
    2.254906
    4 11:24:26.020000  0.786682  0.943536  1.100651  0.835674  2.539893  
    2.257780
```

```
    Time    timedelta64[ns]
    l1              float64
    l2              float64
    l3              float64
    l4              float64
    ecg             float64
    ppg             float64
```

How can I attribute time to this file in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign values to index instead `data.insert`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('.../monday.txt')
data.columns = ['l1','l2','l3','l4','l5','l6']

print("Sensor data: ")
print(data.head())
print(data.dtypes)

nbrMeasurments = sum(1 for line in open('.../monday.txt'))
data.index = pd.timedelta_range('11:24:26', periods=nbrMeasurments-1, freq="5L")

#another solution
#data = data.set_index(pd.timedelta_range('11:24:26', periods=nbrMeasurments-1, freq="5L"))
print("Revised sensor data: ")
print(data.head())
print(data.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `data.set_index(keys="Time", inplace=True)` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
             Time        l1        l2        l3        l4       l5       l6
0        11:24:26  0.787261  0.943828  1.100903  0.835889  2.524946  2.252113
1 11:24:26.005000  0.787068  0.943638  1.100871  0.835882  2.531180  2.253063
2 11:24:26.010000  0.786951  0.943496  1.100779  0.835909  2.531573  2.253395
3 11:24:26.015000  0.786879  0.943553  1.100877  0.835877  2.533841  2.254906
4 11:24:26.020000  0.786682  0.943536  1.100651  0.835674  2.539893  2.257780"""), sep="\s+")

data.set_index(keys="Time", inplace=True)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
                       l1        l2        l3        l4        l5        l6
Time                                                                       
11:24:26         0.787261  0.943828  1.100903  0.835889  2.524946  2.252113
11:24:26.005000  0.787068  0.943638  1.100871  0.835882  2.531180  2.253063
11:24:26.010000  0.786951  0.943496  1.100779  0.835909  2.531573  2.253395
11:24:26.015000  0.786879  0.943553  1.100877  0.835877  2.533841  2.254906
11:24:26.020000  0.786682  0.943536  1.100651  0.835674  2.539893  2.257780
```